# OAuth with Yahoo Asp.net core 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-2.0, yahoo-api, aspnet-contrib

I'm using asp.net core backend with openiddict. I have managed to set up quite a few external providers with no trouble at all, I just set up an app and the callback url would always be https://mysite.co.uk/signin-PROVIDER; however, yahoo don't allow their name to be in any part of the app you create, including the callback url (/signin-yahoo). Any help with this would be great!

I looked on github and found this:
[Yahoo does not allow callbacks with Yahoo in the name](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/issues/213)

Where we are told

> If you set the callback to the root when you create the app, and leave the callback default in your configuration, it works OOTB

But I left it https://www.mysite.co.uk (removed the signin-yahoo) but it doesn't work. There is no online guide that I could find, the only reference was the above comment, which clearly didn't help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have already figured this out, but if you just include the domain name (without the protocol scheme) it works with Yahoo.  So try "www.mysite.co.uk" on the YDN Portal.

My issue is after that. Once the user agrees to the permissions and Yahoo send the callback, the Authentication Handler doesn't seem to recognize it as a callback so I just get a 404.  The Url appears correct, but the Handler never seems to fire and recognize it.  Anyone seen anything like this and have any suggestions?  I assume it is some kind of configuration that I have missed, but I can't seem to find a complete working example in Asp Net Core 2.